# Query Amazon S3 objects by date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an Amazon S3 bucket with the following structure:

%patientId%/%sessionId%/list files that their name is a datetime.
Patient id and session id are unique.
Example bucket with two patients:

- patien1/session1/2021-05-29T061445Z.xxx
- patien1/session1/2021-05-30T061445Z.xxx
- patien2/session2/2021-05-31T061445Z.xxx

Each session may contain thousands of files.
The file name is date, and I prefer (unless there is no other choice) not using "last modified time" of Amazon S3, because we might have a difference between the two dates.

I would like to query by patient/session and time (name of the file), e.g. all files of patient1, session 1 between 2021-05-20 and 2021-05-29.

I understand that using standard Amazon S3 list objects, it is not possible.
I checked AWS Athena, but it seems more suitable for querying Amazon S3 file content, and not by their name.
So, what is the recommended solution for it?
Thanks,

Comment: You may request S3 Inventory and use its outcome for further filtering of your files.

Comment: *"I understand that using standard S3 list objects it is not possible"* - of course it is possible, you need to list all the files and then filter on the client.

Comment: I know it's possible to filter on the client side, but it will not have a good performance. In addition, I may have more than 1000 files, and there is a limit up to 1000.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large number of objects, you might consider **maintaining your own database of objects**. This database should be updated when objects are added/removed. It might sound like a lot of work, but it will perform very well for your application.

You can populate the initial list by using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects in a bucket.

Comment: I think it is time for a canonical answer on this topic, it has come up at least a dozen times in the last week or so. Cannot image how often *you* have seen this or a similar question posted already. Do you by any chance already have written a more extensive answer which covers the inventory in more detail and the alternative of listing and filtering on the client, etc!?

Comment: Thanks. Using my own DB to manage the objects with reference to S3 is the straight forward solution. I was thinking that maybe there is another solution without my DB, but it seems not.